# When should I use the following properties in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

When should I use the following properties

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
return MaterialApp();
return Scaffold();
```

Comment: Unclear. Which property are you talking about?

Comment: You should follow a beginners guide to developing a flutter application, you'll see how MaterialApp and Scaffold widgets should be used. https://flutter.io/docs/reference/widgets

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialApp()` is the one containing or wraps up all your app widgets,it will work without a `Scaffold`, but a `Scaffold` will never work without a `MaterialApp` widget wrapping it if you want to run a standalone app.